# Answer to multiple input prompt in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exe

How can i answer to multiple input prompt in windows batch?

```
echo Directory| CAll C:\"Users"\"myuser"\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ConsoleApp2.exe  
PAUSE
```

This code is works for me, but only for one input. I would like to answer multiple inputs.
 I've tried this, with no luck:

```
(echo input1 && echo input2) | program.exe
```

`program.exe` expects the answers one after the other.

Comment: stepped question format for sure

Comment: Perhaps, you have to wait between input1 and input2

Comment: @jeb not really. The method used by OP does not really work as a answer solution. Answer file is the only robust way to answer multiple back to an executable... if that makes sense :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard It still depends on the program, if the prog flushes the input buffer between required inputs, you have to wait.

Comment: @jeb. Yes, that is where the answer file comes in as a real solution to this problem.

Comment: The `input1<space>` and `input2` looks like it could unexpected with the space `<space>` unless the `program.exe` strips the space from the stdin which it may not.

Comment: Try `(echo input1^& echo input2^& rem/) | program.exe` -- this avoids unwanted trailing spaces, perhaps such were causing problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the most common method is to read the inputs from file.

```
echo input1>in.txt
echo input2>>in.txt
program.exe<in.txt
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, I've been looking for this for a day.

Comment: No problem. You can obviously edit the file manually and not have to echo to it each time. It has to be in list form though. I just did it this way to make it easier. But typically you can pre create the file and just use `>` to read from file as stdin.

Comment: Perpahs you want to do `del in.txt` at the end to clean up the temporary file...

Comment: @aschipfl. Yes in the case where you echo like I did in the example but as mentioned in my comment if the file was pre created it will have to remain. But yeah I will update the answer and explain both.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily do this:

```
<nul set /p="Directory" & <nul set /p="The next answer" | program.exe
```

Comment: I have no luck with this also. Trying to clear the thing: The first question is which wants input:
What would you like to Zip?
File/Directory. 
Then the answer is: Directory
The 2nd q is:
Would you like to delete the original directory? Yes,No.
Then the answer is for example: no
So I've tried this:

**<nul set /p="Directory no" | CAll C:\"Users"\"myuser"\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ConsoleApp2.exe
PAUSE**

Comment: And also `input1 input2 inputN` are place holders. They will be replaced with original input.

Comment: Edited the answer please check!

Comment: Yes I've tried both of them with the same inputs what I wrote.

Comment: I have tried this: **<nul set /p="Directory" & <nul set /p="no" | CAll C:\"Users"\"myuser"\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ConsoleApp2.exe
PAUSE** But now I can't even get to the second question. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: This doesn't work, because the first `<nul set /p="Directory"`won't be piped. Btw. `set /p` isn't useful here, because it drops the line feeds